# Deleting Collection Item in React - map vs for loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating simple to-do app in React.
At the end I was tinkering and wanted achieve same results with various ways.

When I fill array with `map` method in `render`, everything is fine:

```
const todosItems = this.state.todos.map((todo) =>
  <TodoItem name={todo.text} key={todo.id} onClick={(e) => this.deleteButtonClick(todo.id)} />
);
```

When I'm doing the same thing with `for` loop:

```
const todosItems = [];
const todos = this.state.todos;
for (let i = 0; i < todos.length; i++) {
  todosItems.push(<TodoItem name={todos[i].text} key={todos[i].id} onClick={(e) => this.deleteButtonClick(todos[i].id)} />);
}
```

App crashes when I'm deleting one of items:

```
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'todos[i].text')
_loop (index.js:17650)
render (index.js:17659)
finishClassComponent (index.js:5285:149)
performUnitOfWork (index.js:5931:360)
workLoop (index.js:5938)
callCallback (index.js:2613:108)
dispatchEvent
invokeGuardedCallbackDev (index.js:2633)
invokeGuardedCallback (index.js:2649:791)
replayUnitOfWork (index.js:5800:88)
renderRoot (index.js:5960:160)
performWorkOnRoot (index.js:6151)
performWork (index.js:6133:813)
performSyncWork (index.js:6131:155)
interactiveUpdates$1 (index.js:6184:488)
dispatchInteractiveEvent (index.js:3758:115)
dispatchInteractiveEvent
```

Full code: https://github.com/ArturKot95/todo-react/blob/master/index.js

Thank you in advance for help.

EDIT:
Thank you for solutions :D. Most important to me while learning React is thinking that state is something like snapshot in program, must not affecting states of components directly, but work on copies.

Replaced `delete` with `Array.prototype.filter`:

```
deleteButtonClick = (id) => {
    let todos = this.state.todos.slice();
    todos = todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== id);

    this.setState({
        todos: todos
    });
}
```

Replaced `const todos = this.state.todos` with `const todos = this.state.todos.slice()`

Comment: Does your delete work at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `delete` operator cause the error

> When you use delete operator to remove an array element, the array length is not affected.

[deleting array elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Deleting_array_elements)

That means if array has three todo `[{todo}, {todo}, {todo}]`

when you delete the second element: `delete todos[1]`

the todo will be changed to: `[{todo}, empty, {todo}]`

As you see, the length of the array is still three, so the error happens in for statement.

#### why `map` works:

> Map callback is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values, including undefined. It is not called for missing elements of the array (that is, indexes that have never been set, which have been deleted or which have never been assigned a value).

[map description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Description)

PS: when you check errors, you can add some logs to check when happened. :D

Answer (score 2):

Your `delete` operation leaves an empty object in the array and when you the loop get to it it fails to get its `id` property. In general, the code can be improved in many ways:

1. `delete` on an array is not the way to go. Use filter in your delete: `this.setState({this.state.todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== id)})`
2. Working with push is discouraged, simply map/filter your arrays.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this error, you need to change the code in delete method with the below one:

```
    for(var i=0; i<todos.length; i++) {
      if (todos[i].id === id) {
        todos.splice(i, 1)
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now you're directly mutating state in this block of code:

```
const todos = this.state.todos;
for (let todo in todos) {
  if (todos[todo].id === id) {
    delete todos[todo];
  }
}
```

This can cause all sorts of issues in your application. As Meir mentioned, you generally want to map/filter your arrays, but I thought I'd also note that assigning the value of the todos state to a new object, modifying that, and then setting the state with this new object will work with the way you've currently set it up.

```
const todos = Object.assign({}, this.state.todos);
```

Answer (score 1):

Immutable data is the recommended way for react apps.
Don't delete elements of the array. Create a new one without the element you don't want.
The [fastest way](https://jsperf.com/splice-vs-filter) is by pushing the elements to a new array.

```
  deleteButtonClick = (id) => {
      const todos = this.state.todos;
      let res = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < todos.length; i++) {
        if (todos[i].id !== id) {
          res.push(todos[i]);
        }
      }
      this.setState({
        todos: res
      });
  }
```

Since it's a new array, it won't have a problem of having the wrong length caused by delete operator.